# Overwrite specific line in file 2 with content of file 1

Tags: shell-script

I've got 2 files (file 1 contains only 1 line; file 2 contains multiple). I want to replace the 5th line in file 2 with the only line present in file 1. What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: Best?  Highly opinion-based.  For something as simple as this, I'd open file 2 in `vim`, delete the fifth line, and `:read /path/to/file1`.  Done and done.

Comment: Not enough here. Automation is great.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` and `ed` combined make an excellent tool for scripted editing of files.

```
printf '%s\n' '5r file1' 5d w | ed file2
```

This uses `ed` to edit `file2`.  The `printf` command pipes each of its arguments into `ed` one at a time, with a linefeed or newline (`\n`) between each command.

The `ed` commands are:

- `5r file1`  - insert the contents of `file1` **after** line 5
- `5d`        - delete line 5
- `w`         - write the changed `file2` back to disk.  Without this,
  the changes will be discarded when `ed` exits (i.e. quit without save).

Comment: What is the output here? I got three fields where second is number and last one question mark. Etc `printf "%s\n" "${l}i" 'level3(ralt_switch' w | ed koodi.awk` where `koodi.awk` is your last code here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290408/16920.

Comment: @masi The output is `ed`'s extremely verbose and helpful way of telling you what it's up to.  Use `-s` to suppress this vital information.  read and follow the examples in `pinfo ed --node='Introduction to line editing'`.  BTW, you probably don't want to be editing the awk script itself, unless you're just using (a copy of) it as a convenient text file to edit.

Comment: How does this approach differ from sed approach like putting a line to specific line etc `sed -i "2i avatar" file.tex`?

Comment: The main difference is that unlike almost everything else that does "in-place", `ed` is a **real** in-place edit. The modified file has exactly the same inode (so it won't break hard links) and permissions, while `sed` uses a tempfile and renames it over the original, resulting in a new inode and possibly different perms.

Comment: Another difference is that you don't have to have a single-quoted script with embedded newlines (which can be annoying to edit on the command line if you don't use, e.g., `^X^E` to edit the line with `$EDITOR`).  You just put each line of the insert in its own quoted string.  Overall, the syntax of a `sed` multi-line insert is a minor PITA compared to `ed`'s.

Answer (score 1):

```
vim /path/to/file1 -c '5' -c 'delete 1' -c '4' -c 'read /path/to/file2' -c 'w /path/to/file3' -c 'q!'
```

This will use `vim` to open `file1`, go to the fifth line, delete it, insert the contents of `file2` where that line used to be, and save the result to a new file, `file3`.